# What is the socket size for Kia wheels?

Tags: wheels, kia, sportage

I drive Kia Sportage 2018

I want to buy a socket that fits my impact driver to help me change my car's tyres.

What size socket shall I get?

Update:

I bought a 19mm socket but was too small

Comment: You should be setting those wheel torques with a torque wrench, not an impact wrench.

Comment: I will do the initial un-tiie to the socket manually, the impact will do the rest

Comment: Have you tried measuring the supplied tool? That's the easiest way to tell. It'll most likely be 19 or 21mm

Comment: Remove one wheel bolt then take it into your favorite auto store to see if store assistance can determine socket size or do it yourself if there's a shelf of individual sockets to fit into.